# how do i escape a variable in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Please see the following:
https://regex101.com/r/gG3eO8/1

What I want to do is instead of using a constant string, in this case 'I'm H1', I want to insert a variable there so that value is dynamic, following is what i tried but guess i'm not escaping it properly

```
var value = "random string";
"/<h1>.*?" + value + ".*?<\/h1>/g"
```

What would be the right way to escape the above?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? You shouldn't use regular expressions to match HTML things.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RegExp` constructor.

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&")
    };
}
var reg = new RegExp("<h1>.*?" + RegExp.escape(value) + ".*?</h1>", "g");
```

Comment: try `var value = 'My name is "A"';`

Comment: why would you escape when the question's example doesn't need escaping? Overengineer only when the normal solution is insufficient...

Comment: there is no function called `RegExp.escape`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for `<h1>` elements that contain a certain string value, you can simply iterate those elements with DOM functions.

```js
var value = "I'm H1";

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('h1'), function(el) {
  var t = el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
  if (t.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    alert('Found it!');
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>I'm H1 buddy</h1>
<h1>I'm also H1</h1>
<h1>Hi I'm H1</h1>
```

It will show an alter two times in this case.

If you have HTML in a variable, you can create a temporary `<div>` element and set its `.innerHTML` property to create a root node to search from.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing your question is that you want to prevent the injection of HTML into your page. Fortunately, this is a problem that's been well-solved before!

If you're in the browser, you might be using jQuery

```
var $el = $('<h1 />').text(myVariable);
```

If not, you might pull [these lines](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L44-L57) from Mustache:

```
var entityMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#39;',
  '/': '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml (string) {
  return String(string).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function fromEntityMap (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}

var el = '<h1>' + escapeHtml(myVariable) + '</h1>';
```